# PHP converting 'trying to get property of non-object' to a default value?

Tags: php, variables

I want to do a calculation where the function has to retrieve numbers from different places in the database. However the numbers or the object containing the numbers are not guaranteed to exist since it's not mandatory to fill everything. This is done in case the user is not filling some part of the input, I want to return a default number.

I need a quick way of converting any unknown properties into a default value (i.e zero) in this particular function, so that it can continue calculating some part of it with no errors.

It looks like this:

```
$request['doh_piutang'] = round(($aktivaLancar->piutang/$performaLabaRugi->omzet)*30);
$request['doh_persediaan'] = round(($aktivaTetap->inventaris_lain/$performaLabaRugi->hpp)*30);
$request['doh_hutang'] = round(($pasivaHutang->dagang/$performaLabaRugi->hpp)*30);
$request['kebutuhan_modal_kerja'] = round((($performaLabaRugi->omzet/30)*$request['doh_piutang'])+(($performaLabaRugi->omzet/30)*$request['doh_persediaan'])+(($pasivaHutang->dagang/30)*$request['doh_hutang']));
$request['maksimal_kredit_cma'] = round(40/100*($performaLabaRugi->sisa_penghasilan_bersih-$performaLabaRugi->angsuran_bank_lain)*$usulanKredit->jangka_waktu_per_bulan);
$request['maksimal_angsuran_kredit'] = round(50/100*($performaLabaRugi->sisa_penghasilan_bersih-$performaLabaRugi->angsuran_bank_lain));
$request['maksimal_kredit_taksasi_agunan'] = round(60/100*$usulanKredit->total_agunan);
```

Say the $aktivaLancar->piutang is not set, I want to just convert it to zero or some other number, instead of throwing `Trying to get property 'piutang' of non-object`.

Otherwise I had to check every single variables which I want to avoid doing unless I have no choice.

Comment: Why would you like to fiddle around with variables that might or might not be even initialized? That looks like a horrible design decision, open to tons of problems

Comment: You should check to see if you have vars before you try to manipulate them.  Or, when the stdclass object is created give them a default of 0.

Comment: @NicoHaase it is for an android app where a user might or might not enter values which are not enforced. In case the user is not entering value, I want to return zero instead of errors from the api.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something like ?:

```
$var = (isset($aktivaLancar)) ? $aktivaLancar->piutang : 0;
```

Comment: I think that is exactly that kind of code the OP tries to avoid